# EGit plugin overwriting commit history - Git, Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am on a small development team, using GitHub for source control. I am used to using Git right on the command line but the two developers I am collaborating with prefer to use EGit in Eclipse. What we are seeing happen is when they do a commit & push from EGit, all other prior commits done by other developers are lost in the remote GitHub.

Is this behavior something anyone has experienced before?  I am also not familiar with EGit at all.  Is it possible they are missing steps or using the plugin incorrectly?

Comment: Are the other two developers pushing to the same remote branch as you are?

Comment: Yes they are, @Jubobs. Project just started. We only have a master branch and the one remote.

Comment: Ask them what they are doing. Maybe they are force-pushing (which is a no-no).